# how to parse string with '-' to node js local script?

Tags: python, node.js, shell

I'm using a local node js script to do some work with string.

I get stuck in parsing a string with '-' to the local node js script.

render.js:

```
#! /usr/bin/env -S node -r esm
let argv = require('yargs')
    .usage('$0 [string]')
    .argv;

console.log(argv._[0])
```

```
$ node -r esm render.js  'c -a < b helo fdsfs'
[ 'c-a < b helo fdsfs' ]
$ node -r esm render.js  '-a < b helo fdsfs'
[ '' ]
```

I guess '-a' is treated as an unknown option.

How to avoid this situation.

Actually I'm using a python subprocess to run this node js script in python.

Comment: Check the [yargs-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs-parser) package

Comment: @TamasSzoke no difference with yargs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the string as an option:

```
$ node -r esm render.js --data='-a < b helo fdsfs'
```

Modified script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env -S node -r esm
let argv = require('yargs')
    .usage('$0 [string]')
    .argv;

console.log(argv.data)
```

Comment: `node -r esm render.js  --data='-a < b helo fdsfs' ` works.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add the dashes in the answer.